# Is there a name for words like "aftermath"?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for words like "aftermath" or "windfall" that originally had a completely different meaning to the sense in which they are used today? Windfall for example, originally referred to fruits shaken off trees by the wind but has come to mean a stroke of good fortune. Idiomatic is the closest I could come up with but I am not sure if that is accurate.

Comment: Yes, [idiom](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idiom) works. See definition 1.

Comment: I mean, aren't the terms being used **metaphorically**? I imagine they would be some subclass of **metaphors**.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an example of *semantic shift*. In the example of ‘windfall’, its meaning has widened, and it has become a *metaphor* for a stroke of good fortune.

There is more information about this on Wikipedia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change

I am not aware if there is a specific term for *examples* of semantic shift.

Comment: This wikipedia article cites "broadcast" as an example of semantic shift and classifies it as a metaphor. My examples are pretty much in the same category. Thanks for the reference.